# No space left on device ( linux )

Tags: linux, filesystems, redhat

When I try to create a file, it's giving "No space left on device"

I tried to fetch inode usage :

```
$df -ih ~
```

I am getting : `IUse% = 77%`

And when I do this to fetch disk usage :

```
$df -h ~
```

I am getting : `Use% = 11%`

What's going wrong? How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

you check the ~ (Home Folder) and it can be missleading.
best practice is to use 
df -kh *
du -sh /
fdisk -l
https://www.tecmint.com/check-linux-disk-usage-of-files-and-directories/